# Law of Poiseuille : $F = kR^4$

Tags: derivatives, proof-verification

French physiologist Jean Louis Poiseuille denoted the amount of blood at unit time in the blood vessel as below :

$$F = kR^4$$ 
$F$ : Amount of Flood of Blood $R$ : Radius of Blood Vessel

When $R$ increases 7%, how much would $F$ be increased?

---

**my solution**

$dF/dR = 4kR^3$ thus, $4k(1.07)^3 $

Is it correct?

Comment: I thought it is just $1.07^{4}-1$…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its right till you dont plug in the values.  A way can be take logs in your original equation . This gives us $\ln (F)=\ln (k)+4\ln (R) $ differentiating we have $\frac {dF}{F}=\frac {4dr}{R} $ now multiplying by $100$ we have $\text {percent change in F}=4×7=28\text {percent} $

Comment: surprising.. log transformation works in this way.. thx

Comment: Yiu are welcome!

Comment: This does not seem right.  If $R$ increases by a factor of $1.07$ then $R^4$ should increase by a factor of $(1.07)^4=1.31\ldots$ corresponding to an increase of about 31%.